# Is it possible to dynamically create and store pointers for functions for which we don't know the number and type of arguments?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-functions

I've been given a bunch of dummy functions, each one with its own return type, number (and types) of arguments and I'm trying to figure out a way to create function pointers of the correct type to them automatically, then store them inside a map to be retrieved at will. In a nutshell, I'm stuck at creating the actual function pointers. The way of storing them in a map is a separate, follow-up question, due to their variable types.

I think that templates are the way to go, and I've tried creating a templated function that returns the appropriately-typed pointer given the address and types of a function. I think it could not be possible though, so any input is appreciated.

Code for the aforementioned function:

```
template <typename retType, typename ... argTypes> retType makeFuncPtr(void* funcAddr) {
    retType (*ptr)(argTypes) = funcAddr;
    return ptr;
}
```

I'm getting an error "Declaration type contains unexpanded parameter pack 'argTypes'". What am I doing wrong and also which is the appropriate return type for this function, as I'm not actually sure about it?

Comment: *"The way of storing them in a map is a separate, follow-up question"*, and another one: How do you use it ? I mean how do you know how many and which argument to pass to your stored function ?

Comment: What I mean is that I think it is a [XY_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Jarod42 An outside, specially structured message comes, which contains the function name and the arguments with which it should be ran after the name, in the correct sequence. My job is to decode the message, grab the proper pointer from the map and run the associated function with the given arguments.

Comment: Shouldn't X `map`s (one for each type of message) more appropriate ? Why type-erase the type ?

Comment: @Jarod42 can you explain a bit? What do you mean by 'message type'? There is only a single message format, which is like that: [string with the function name][number of args (N)][argID (here 1)][value of arg1][arg2][value2]...[argN][valueN]

Comment: Seems that all `argX` have the same type (I suppose string from now), So I mean something like `map<string, std::function<void()>> f0; map<string, std::function<void(string)>> f1;map<string, std::function<void(string, string)>> f2; /*.. up to appropriate value*/`. (`std::function` or function pointers).

Comment: @Jarod42 My bad, they're not of the same type. Still, too many maps seem impractical to me at handling.

Comment: How about `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const Message&)>> funcs` ? (with probably register function which "transform/wrap" `void (*)(int, std::string)` into `std::function<void(const Message&)>`).

Comment: Why are you not just writing a switch statement based on the message?

Comment: The switch would become huge and unwieldy. Because of the format of the message, there are lots of possible messages. But anyway, I think I've found another way to solve this, which I'll be writing as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error you ask about is because in the line:

```
retType (*ptr)(argTypes) = funcAddr;
```

there is no ... after argTypes. Note this would not actually fix the situation because a void pointer can not be converted to some other kind of pointer without a cast. And also you could not convert the function pointer to retType.

If the functions have different signatures this is a fairly tricky problem,  I suggest you take a look at libffi, the tricky part here is not storing the function pointers (so long as they are not non-static member functions you can simply cast to void * and store that), the tricky part is using the stored pointer value to make a call.

libffi gives you the ability to describe a function's calling convention, return type and expected arguments. You could then write code that compares the arguments you actually received and either convert or produce an error as appropriate. With C++ it would even be possible to produce that description programmatically (your template function would take a function pointer as a parameter then use the parameter pack to map to the libffi argument type values).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since a void pointer cannot be converted to any other kind of pointer without a cast, then could you suggest a way to get the function's address? By the way, I can't use libffi if it uses the STL due to this code being written for an embedded system (we use a different implementation of the STL called ETL, specially made for embedded usage

Comment: libffi is C with some assembly, you would have to look to see whether it is supported on your particular platform. To get a pointer with the function signature the cast would be like "auto fp = static_cast<retType (*)(argTypes...)>(vp);" or "retType (*fp)(argTypes...) = static_cast<retType (*)(argTypes...)>(vp);" if not using auto.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir you cannot cast a function pointer to void*, but you can instead use a fixed function pointer type. (Size of function pointer may not be the same as size of data pointer.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I've never experienced problems casting regular functions (whether free functions or static member functions) to void *, it's only member functions that have such problems (and there only if the member is actually a virtual).

Comment: @SoroneHaetir the standard permits function pointers to be different size from data pointers. You don't see it much today but it is nevertheless technically allowed, so for portability you should stick to the rules. (Furthermore, member function pointers even for nonvirtuals are typically larger than data pointers even on modern architectures.)

Comment: Honestly, I've not cared about strict portability for two decades, functionally portable sure but not strict. If you care about strict portability you aren't going to be using something like libffi to begin with.